# Recursive merge nested Map in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have some nested maps like:

```
val map1 = Map("key1"->1, "key2"->Map("x"->List(1,2)))
val map2 = Map("key3"->3, "key2"->Map("y"->List(3,4)))
```

And I want to merge them to obtain the result map like;

```
val res = Map("key1"->1, "key2"->Map("x"->List(1,2), "y"->List(3,4)), "key3"->3)
```

So nested maps should also be merged.
The type of the maps and nested maps can be assumed as Map[String, Any]. It's considered an exception if the two maps have conflict keys (eg. values of the same key are different, except that the value is a nested map).

Is there some elegant solution to this?
Thanks!

Comment: what if the same key (like "key2" in the example) points to a value that's not a map? E.g. key1 -> 1 in map1 and key1 -> 2 in map2.
What if one value is a map and the other isn't?

You have a code (bad) smell here by the way

Comment: This data structure is, well... ugly Oo. I can't find a decent solution. I'd try to use foldLeft, but with both Int and Map as values in your higher map...

Comment: In fact that's some deserialized json document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
type MapType = Map[String, Any]

def merge(map1 : MapType, map2 : MapType) = (map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet)
  .map(key => key -> mergeValues(map1.get(key), map2.get(key)))
  .toMap

private def mergeValues(o1 : Option[Any], o2 : Option[Any]) = (o1, o2) match {
  case (Some(v1 : MapType), Some(v2 : MapType)) => v1 ++ v2
  case _ => (o1 orElse o2).get
}
```

You can modify the `mergeValues` function to support additional cases (i.e. situation when the same key points to 2 values which are not maps - at the moment will return the first of the values).

Comment: you could make `mergeValues` a function within the merge function

Comment: Agreed, it can be even inlined within `map`, though one benefit of having it separated can be access for easy testing of the `mergeValues` function itself should there be a few more complex cases added.

Comment: Thanks! However I changed the `v1 ++ v2` to `merge(v1, v2)` so that it supports multiple level of nested maps.

Answer (score 3):

```
type MapType = Map[String, Any]

def merge(map1 : MapType, map2 : MapType) = (map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet)
  .map(key => key -> mergeValues(map1.get(key), map2.get(key)))
  .toMap

private def mergeValues(o1 : Option[Any], o2 : Option[Any]) = (o1, o2) match {
  case (Some(v1), Some(v2)) => merge(v1.asInstanceOf[MapType], v2.asInstanceOf[MapType])
  case _ => (o1 orElse o2).get
}
```

Improved version of [norbert-radyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470454/norbert-radyk) with :

- Multiple nested level support suggested by [darkjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568084/darkjh)
- Scala 2.11 compatibility to avoid this error : `non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] (the underlying of MapType) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
  case (Some(v1 : MapType), Some(v2 : MapType)) => v1 ++ v2`